# OpenGl instanced rendering in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to render many objects through instancing. However the function

```
glDrawArraysInstanced()
```

seems to have been removed in Qt5. It exists in the QOpenGLFunctions class in [Qt4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions-4-2-core.html#glDrawArraysInstanced), but not in [Qt5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html).

What is the correct way to use instancing in Qt5 then?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions-4-5-core.html says otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as QOpenGLFunctions in Qt 4 (QOpenGL* classes have been all introduced in Qt 5).

Both of your links are indeed pointing at two different **Qt 5** classes:
 `QOpenGLFunctions_4_2_Core` and `QOpenGLFunctions`.

And both of those classes are OpenGL function resolvers, so you can write something like:

```
// get the object from somewhere (usually, a QOpenGLContext)
QOpenGLFunctions *functions = ...
functions->glCreateShader(...);
functions->glDrawArrays(...);
```

The difference between them is:

- QOpenGLFunctions aims at the "common subset" between OpenGL ES 2 and OpenGL 2.1 + FBO. So it will work both on "desktop" and "embedded", provided you're fine with that subset; you can develop on your desktop computer and then deploy to embedded and you won't need to change your GL code. (In theory.)
- QOpenGLExtraFunctions aims at the "common subset" between OpenGL ES 3.1 and OpenGL 4.3 (?). Same thing, but bigger version, so more features: compute shaders, draw indirect, samplers, immutable textures, transform feedback, and the like. A subset of it will still work if you only have OpenGL 2 or 3, provided you've got the right extensions.
- QOpenGLFunctions_4_2_Core, and all the other similar `_X_Y_Profile` classes, only work in a Desktop OpenGL context compatible with the class name (for instance, `4_2_Core` will work with any OpenGL context whose version is equal or bigger than 4.2, and Core or Compatibility profile).

If you want to use instancing, you can choose either a suitable `QOpenGLFUnctions_X_Y_Profile` if you only aim desktop (so you need at least version 3.1), or `QOpenGLExtraFunctions`. Both have `glDrawArraysInstanced`.